# Latent Modeling of Non-exchangable data or de Finneti on time-series

Tags: time-series, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, exchangeability

De Finneti's theorem applies on infinetely exchangeable sequences and allows building probabilistic models with latent variables that allow us to describe them. Is there a similar theorem for time-series data? Can we apply in a similar manner a latent-variable-based model on non-exchangable data with some theoretical guarantees?

Answer (score 1):

An example for longitudinal data comes to my mind: Markov exchangeable processes are mixtures of Markov Chains.

In a Markov exchangeable process (sometimes "partial exchangeable") the number of transitions for each couple of states is a sufficient statistics. Under some additional hypothesis (recurrence), Diaconis and Freedman (Annals of Probability 1980) demonstrated that it is a mixture of Markov Chains.

There are specific works on the Bayesian analysis (see e.g. Quintana), and works on mixtures of reversible Markov Chains (Diaconis Rolles).